# FutureBuilder class argument future is an async function with arguments

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I'm developing a Flutter mobile application which uses Google APIs. In one of the screens of my application I want to let the user type in a place (city, address, ...) and call the Google Places API to generate a list of suggestions based on user input. Whenever the text input changes a new GET request is issued.

To handle user input I am using a TextEditingController and in order to have a better user experience I want to use FutureBuilder class in order to show a loading spinner when the data is not ready. This is the code:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Info extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/info';

  @override
  _InfoState createState() => _InfoState();
}

class _InfoState extends State<Info> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Start listening to changes.
    controller.addListener(buildPredictionList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Info'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextField(
            controller: controller,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: buildPredictionList(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildPredictionList() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchPredictions,                      // <-- Error! fetchPredictions expects a parameter!
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              Prediction pred = snapshot.data[index];
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.pin_drop),
                  title: Text('${pred.description}'),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}

class Prediction {
  final String placeId;
  final String description;

  Prediction({this.placeId, this.description});

  factory Prediction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Prediction(
      placeId: json['place_id'],
      description: json['description'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Prediction>> fetchPredictions(String query) async {
  const GOOGLE_API_KEY = '...';
  final lat = 40.758058;
  final lng = -73.985626;
  final radius = 2000;
  final lang = 'en';
  var url =
      'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$query&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY&location=$lat,$lng&radius=$radius&language=$lang&strictbounds=true';

  final response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var predictionsJson = json.decode(response.body)['predictions'] as List;
    List<Prediction> predictions = predictionsJson
        .map((predictionJson) => Prediction.fromJson(predictionJson))
        .toList();
    return predictions;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch Predictions');
  }
}
```

My async function `fetchPredictions` expects an argument, which is the query string used for the GET request (so the input address, city, ...). But I cannot wrap this in an anonymous function because the `future` argument is expecting a return type of `Future`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you already have the query string?  If so, why can't you call `fetchPredictions(queryString)`? The `future` parameter expects a return type of `Future`, and `fetchPredictions(queryString)` would return a `Future`.

Comment: I solved the problem. I didn't understand the documentation. Thank you.